# Setting default keyboard layout application-specific?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-layout

I'm using WinXP with the keyboard layout language bar set to default. My problem is, I want to set the keyboard layout individually from startup of said application. In Outlook I need umlauts so I use the German layout but in eclipse I use US layout because the German one isn't ideal for programming. Is it possible to define an application parameter so I don't have to switch it manually every time I start the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to Control Panel / Regional and Language Options / Languages / Details / Key Settings", you can define hotkeys for language changes.

You may couple this with a macro language like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to define a macro that starts your application with the correct language / keyboard layout.

Comment: +1 That's a nice and clean solution! I like it :-D

Comment: yup, thats definitely a great idea

Comment: So I guess the answer is no, you cannot setup WinXP to remember the keyboard setting used for an application, and use it directly from the start (you have to change it manually after start of the application).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's an exact solution for you but [you could try LangOver](http://www.langover.com/)

Basically you don't have to change the layout, it will change you're words to the language you need by I think using something like Google Translate or a translating tool of your choice. So you could leave it US-layout and get German words anyway.

> With LangOver you can change your
>   language in keyboard. To change
>   language with LangOver you have to
>   click "F10" and your text will be
>   fixed!
>
> - Use "F10": (switch between languages) - Just click F10 – and your
>     text will be fixed!
> - Use "SHIFT+F10": for converting upper / lowercase text: ABC<>abc
> - Use "F6": For reversing a text
> - Use "Control+G": TO search in Google

I'll keep looking for a tool to set your layout to an application anyway ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the [US international keyboard](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306560), which is the normal US keyboard, but you also get umlauts, ß, ç...

I write in Portuguese, German and also program – everything using the same keyboard layout.